# pass a parameter to a view function (form) in a for loop to populate form flask wtforms sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I want to be able to display the rows of a database model on my web page as an updatable prepopulated form! I can display the rows on the page easily and I can add a link to each to open a seperate page to edit each row, I can also display each row with the update form, but I cant display the form populated. here is my code:

```
@bp.route('/stock', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@bp.route('/stock/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def stock(id=None):
    if id is not None:
        obj = Stock.query.get_or_404(id)
        form = AddStockForm(request.form, obj=obj)
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            form.populate_obj(obj)
            db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('stock.stock'))
    else:
        form = AddStockForm()
        page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
        stock = Stock.query.order_by(Stock.id.desc()).paginate(
        page, current_app.config['ITEMS_PER_PAGE'], False)
        next_url = url_for('stock.stock', page=stock.next_num) \
            if stock.has_next else None
        prev_url = url_for('stock.stock', page=stock.prev_num) \
            if stock.has_prev else None
        return render_template('stock/stock.html',form=form, title=Stock, stock=stock.items,
             next_url=next_url, prev_url=prev_url)
```

and the stock.html code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="main">
    <h2>Stock</h2>
    <div class="books"><a href="{{ url_for('stock.upload_stock') }}">Upload Stock csv</a> 
</div>
    <div class="books"><a href="{{ url_for('stock.add_stock') }}">Add a new Item</a></div>
    {% for s in stock %}
        {% include 'stock/_stock.html' %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

_stock.html code:

```
<div class="stock">
    <div class="c0"><img src="{{ s.image_url }}" alt="{{ s.image_filename }}"></div>

        <form action="{{ url_for('stock._stock', id=s.id) }}" method="post", 
           enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <div>SKU<BR> {{ s.id }} </div>
            <div>Date of Purchase<br>{{ form.date(class="input") }}</div>
            <div>Description<br>{{ form.description(class="input") }}</div>
            <div>Market<br>{{ form.event(class="input") }}</div>
            <div>Purchase Price<br>{{ form.achat(class="input") }}</div>
            <div>Sale Price<br>{{ form.vente(class="input") }}</div>
            <div>Sold<br>{{ form.sold(class="input") }}</div>
            <div>{{ form.submit(class="submit") }}</div>
        </form>

</div>
```

on google developer tools each form shows stock/4 or 3 but this does not seem to then populate the form. there are no error messages. 
thanks in advance for any help.
regards Paul

EDIT
hi @Greg Cowell, Thank you for your help, I have addapted your code but I Get this error

```
  File "/var/www/accounts/bdf/templates/base.html", line 30, in root
</body>
  File "/var/www/accounts/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/runtime.py", line 262, in call
return __obj(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/accounts/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 370, in url_for
return appctx.app.handle_url_build_error(error, endpoint, values)
  File "/var/www/accounts/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2215, in handle_url_build_error
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/var/www/accounts/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
  File "/var/www/accounts/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 358, in url_for
endpoint, values, method=method, force_external=external
  File "/var/www/accounts/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 2020, in build
raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method, self)
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'stock.stock'. Did you forget to specify values ['id']?
[pid: 29588|app: 0|req: 1/1] 192.168.0.13 () {48 vars in 1095 bytes} [Sun Nov 17 09:26:58 2019] GET /index =>
```

here is the adapted code:

```
@bp.route('/stock/stock/<int:id>/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def stock(id=None):
    if id is not None:
        group = current_user.group()
        try:
            stock = Stock.query.filter_by(group=group, id=id).one()
        except NoResultFound:
            flash('Invalid account.')
            return redirect(url_for('stock.add_stock'))
        accounts = current_user.group().stock
        form = AddStockForm()
        form.stock_id.default = stock.id
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            if form.modify.data:
                for s in stock:
                    if (
                        item.id == form.stock_id.data and
                        item.id != form.stock_id.default
                    ):
                        flash('Another account already has this name.')
                        return redirect(url_for('stock.add_stock', id=id))
                stock.id = form.stock_id.data
                db.session.add(stock)
            db.session.commit()
        form.process()  # Do this after validate_on_submit or breaks CSRF token
    else:
        form = AddStockForm()
        page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
        stock = Stock.query.order_by(Stock.id.desc()).paginate(
             page, current_app.config['ITEMS_PER_PAGE'], False)
        next_url = url_for('stock.stock', page=stock.next_num) \
            if stock.has_next else None
        prev_url = url_for('stock.stock', page=stock.prev_num) \
            if stock.has_prev else None
    return render_template('stock/stock.html',form=form, title=Stock, stock=stock.items,
         next_url=next_url, prev_url=prev_url)
```

SECOND EDIT

I added this to the top of the view function:

```
@bp.route('/stock', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

which got rid of the above error, I then got a similar error for the "stock.html code"

```
    {% for s in stock %}
        {% include 'stock/_stock.html' %}
    {% endfor %}
```

which I changed to:

```
   {% include {{ url_for('stock._stock', id=['s.id']) }} %}
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a different method for prepopulating forms.

In summary, I set the default for each form field and process the form before rendering. In the example below I set the value for the account_name field default using `form.account_name.default = account.accname` and then call `form.process()` before rendering the form.

```
@web.route('/accounts/modify/<int:accno>/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def modify_account(accno):
    """
    Modify or delete accounts.
    Return a form for modifying accounts or process submitted
    form and redirect to Accounts HTML page.
    """
    group = current_user.group()
    try:
        account = Account.query.filter_by(group=group, accno=accno).one()
    except NoResultFound:
        flash('Invalid account.')
        return redirect(url_for('.accounts_page'))
    accounts = current_user.group().accounts
    form = ModifyAccountForm()
    form.account_name.default = account.accname

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.modify.data:
            for item in accounts:
                if (
                    item.accname == form.account_name.data and
                    item.accname != form.account_name.default
                ):
                    flash('Another account already has this name.')
                    return redirect(url_for('.modify_account', accno=accno))
            account.accname = form.account_name.data
            db.session.add(account)
            db.session.commit()
        elif form.delete.data:
            for transaction in current_user.group().transactions:
                if transaction.account == account:
                    unknown_account = Account.query.filter_by(
                        group=current_user.group(), accname='Unknown').one()
                    transaction.account = unknown_account
                    db.session.add(transaction)
                    db.session.commit()
            db.session.delete(account)
            db.session.commit()
        elif form.cancel.data:
            pass
        return redirect(url_for('.accounts_page'))

    form.process()  # Do this after validate_on_submit or breaks CSRF token

    return render_template(
        'modify_account.html', form=form, accno=accno, menu="accounts")
```

Comment: Hi @Greg Cowell, Thank you for your reply, I have adapted your code, but I get an error shown in my question, this is because the link to this page in "base.html" nav bar expects an `['id']` which I dont want to give at this point.

Comment: I think you need a single large form for the page. The form code will need to dynamically generate fields for each of your model’s records. Your HTML template for the form will then need to loop through the list of fields so they are displayed. My example code will just help you with pre-populating the form fields from your view code.

Comment: Take a look at FieldList classes for some insight into how to build the single large form for all your model‘s records.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for coming back to me, Yes I can do that by displaying the rows on the main page, with a link on each to open an edit page, but as a short cut I am hoping that I can show a form for each row all on one page (with pagination) which then can be quickly edited on the same page. This app is an accounting database for my buisiness hosted on a local network, I want to have one page with every transaction displayed where each is an updateable form a "grande livre" or general ledger. At the moment I use libre office base, I want to try to reproduce this as an accessable web app.

Comment: If I understand your requirements correctly, you want to display all your records on a single page and edit them in situ using form fields. You have the choice of 1. A single large dynamically generated form with a single submit button. 2. A page which has a form for each record and an individual submit button for each record. I believe you want option 2. Please confirm and I will give you some suggestions for how to approach it.

Comment: Good morning, thank you for coming back. you are right option 2  is what I want, I will be back on line in 12 hours. Warm regard

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202555/discussion-between-pascale-and-greg-cowell).

Answer (score 1):

To make an HTML page which has a form for each record and an individual submit button for each record, you need to create multiple forms in your view/route function and then loop through them all in your HTML template.

View/route:

```
@web.route('/stocks', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def stocks():
    """Return Stocks HTML page."""
    stocks = Stock.query.all()
    forms = []
    for stock in stocks:
        form = ModifyStockForm()
        form.stock_id.default = stock.stock_id
        form.stock_name.default = stock.stock_name
        forms.append(form)

    for form in forms:
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            if form.modify.data:
                stock = Stock.query.filter_by(stock_id=form.stock_id.data).one()
            stock.stock_name = form.stock_name.data
            db.session.add(stock)
            db.session.commit()
        elif form.delete.data:
            stock = Stock.query.filter_by(stock_id=form.stock_id.data).one()
            db.session.delete(stock)
            db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('.stocks'))

        form.process()  # Do this after validate_on_submit or breaks CSRF token

return render_template('stocks.html', forms=forms, stocks=stocks)
```

Template:

```
<h2>Stocks:</h2>

   {% for form in forms %}

    <form method="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

        {{ form.stock_id }}
        {{ form.stock_name }}
        {{ form.modify }}
        {{ form.delete }}

    </form>

   {% endfor %}
```

I've put a complete example in this repo: [Example of multiple forms on a single page](https://github.com/gregcowell/multiforms)